# scrollView bounds size is always zero

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am teaching myself IOS development and I am running into an issue with one of the excercises I am trying to do.  Basically I have a list of pictures I want to display, so I created a Table View with a list of these pictures, and the goal is to click on a cell and show the picture autozooms to the size of the screen.  I have ARC turned off so I can learn to manage memory myself.

When I select a cell in the table view it invokes a UIViewController that has a scroll view and an image view.

[image: storyboard snapshot]

This is how I connected the outlets:

[image: How the outlets are connected]

In the PhotoViewController's implementation under the method viewWillAppear, I wrote this code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

[self.scrollView setZoomScale:1 animated:NO];
CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
NSLog(@"@@@AMRO scrollboundsSize  is width %f and height %f", boundsSize.width, 
boundsSize.height);
```

I need the boundsSize to help me figure out how to zoom my picture.  The problem is that it always reads zero.  I know based on the the storyboard, the boundsSize is 320x455.  Obviously I do not want to hard code it.

In my .h of that PhotoViewController, I defined:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Now if in ViewWillAppear, I do this:

```
CGRect fullScreenRect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:fullScreenRect];
```

Then I get bounds to be defined, but the size is off, its  width 320.000000 and height 548.000000.  I understand that the height of 548 is probably because it includes the Title Bar and the Tab Bar at the bottom.  Is there a way for me correctly set the bounds based on the viewing are of 320 by 455 as seen in the story board. I looked at other code snippets of folks doing the same thing and they do not even allocate the scrollView, is that because ARC is ON and that is something that is managed automatically?

If I use this approach, then I do get the correct size, but is this the right approach, I have seen examples where scrollview was never initialized and yet they have the bounds set correctly

```
CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
self.scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:viewBounds];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the method `viewDidAppear` to get bounds and other sizes instead of `viewWillAppear`.

 Your scrollview bounds still might not be initialized when `viewWillAppear` is executed.

Comment: Interesting feedback, I initially had the code in viewDidLoad and decided to move it to viewWillAppear as that is called later.  Now that I tried viewDidAppear, I am getting the correct bound size, but the image does not show up anymore, its all black.

Comment: I spoke too soon, I removed self.view=self.scrollView at the end and that fixed it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I have seen other examples of implementation where they used viewWillAppear and they got it to work there, any reason why.  Could it be that there system timing happened to suffice that the bounds was set by then?

Comment: Glad it works now !

I really can't say what is causing that, I would bet on system timing too !

Comment: @user1437830 that's probably because you are now using auto-layout, which changes a little bit the timing of initializing the views. Earlier when auto-layout doesn't exist, viewWillAppear always worked fine

Comment: Great observation, yes other code samples did not use auto layout.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute geometry-related code *before* the view appears on screen, you could place it in viewDidLayoutSubviews

```
@interface CustomViewController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews; // variable name could be re-factored

@end

@implementation CustomViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    // only after layoutSubviews executes for subviews, do constraints and frames agree (WWDC 2012 video "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout")

    if (self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews) {

        // execute geometry-related code...
    }

    self.isFirstTimeViewDidLayoutSubviews = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a great idea too.  For now, I am getting away viewDidAppear